# How is the C# Delegate Action written in F#?

Tags: f#, delegates

How to implement a C# Action in F#?

I have the following code in C# code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new ViewModel();
            DataContext = ViewModel;
        }

        private void ListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object _, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _closeAdorner();
        
            // listView here equals object _  
            var listView = (ListView)e.Source;
            var grid = (Grid)listView.Parent;
            var selecteditem = (InnerRow)listView.SelectedItem;
            ViewModel.Visit = selecteditem;
            ViewModel.LastName = selecteditem.LastName;
        
            var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(grid);
            if (adornerLayer == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("datagrid does not have have an adorner layer");

            var adorner = new DataGridAnnotationAdorner(grid);
            adornerLayer.Add(adorner);
        
           _closeAdorner = () => adornerLayer.Remove(adorner);
        }
```

I am attempting to translate this into F#:

```
let handlePreviewMouseLeftButtonUp (obj: obj) (a, c) =
      let e = (obj :?> MouseButtonEventArgs)
      let listView = e.Source :?> ListView   // This is the ListView control that was clicked.
      let grid = listView.Parent :?> Grid
          
      let selectedItem = c.InnerRows |> List.filter (fun r -> Some r.Id = c.SelectedInnerRow) |> List.head
    
      let adorner = DataGridAdorner(grid)

      let installAdorner =
        let adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(grid)
        if (adornerLayer.GetAdorners = []) then adornerLayer.Add(adorner) else adornerLayer.Remove(adorner)
```

The last line:
if (adornerLayer.GetAdorners = []) then adornerLayer.Add(adorner) else adornerLayer.Remove(adorner)

**clearly does not compile and is not correct. How is the C# _closeAdorner written to have the same function in F#?**

Thank you.

TIA

Comment: In C# `e` is the second argument, but in F# you're trying to treat the first argument as event args for some reason

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I believe the order is switched in Elmish.WPF -- I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what `_closeAdorner`, `InnerRow`, `DataGridAdorner` and other elements are. Anyway, here I fixed some (not all) of the syntax issues in your code:

```
let handlePreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(obj : obj) (e:MouseButtonEventArgs)  =
    let listView = e.Source        :?> ListView   // This is the ListView control that was clicked.
    let grid     = listView.Parent :?> Grid
        
    let selectedItem = listView.SelectedItem :?> InnerRow//  |> List.filter (fun r -> Some r.Id = c.SelectedInnerRow) |> List.head
    
    let adorner = DataGridAdorner(grid)

    let installAdorner =
        let adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(grid)
        if adornerLayer.GetAdorners(grid) = [||] then adornerLayer.Add(adorner) else adornerLayer.Remove(adorner)
    ()
```

In your constructor you can add the event handler like this:

```
listView.MouseUp.AddHandler(MouseButtonEventHandler(handlePreviewMouseLeftButtonUp))
```

You can also remove it:

```
listView.MouseUp.RemoveHandler(MouseButtonEventHandler(handlePreviewMouseLeftButtonUp))
```

To create generic `Action`s you do it like this:

```
let action = Action<_,_>(handlePreviewMouseLeftButtonUp)
```

Where the `<_,_>` corresponds to the number of parameters the action receives.

Comment: I believe this will accomplish my task, but how does one write code as an "Action" in F# ?  Thanks.

Comment: I fixed the function declaration because it was wrong, and also added how you add the handler to the event